# Why Don't the Death Eaters Kill Harry Physically

Tags: harry-potter

We know that someone actually died while playing Quidditch. So why didn't anyone, such as Voldemort or Draco, just poke a quill in Harry's eye to kill him?

Comment: That would just blind him in one eye. You should have suggested a machete , you can do a lot more with that.

Comment: I'd imagine it's for the same reason you wouldn't beat someone to death if you had a gun. Magic is quicker, easier, more reliable, less messy and less traceable.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention Quidditch, recall that Voldemort/Quirrell *did* try to kill Harry while he was playing a game in *The Philosopher's Stone* by jinxing his broom.

Other attempts at assassination were also done, although most of them likely planned to use magic to do so, rather than stabbing him with a quill. Perhaps the most relevant to the phrasing of your question is that Barty Crouch Jr lured Harry to Moody's office in *The Goblet of Fire* to kill him personally.

Apart from that, Voldemort obviously tried to kill him in *Goblet of Fire* to use his blood in his own resurrection. Death Eaters also crashed the wedding of Bill and Fleur, presumably with the primary aim of killing Harry. Death Eaters also tried to kidnap Harry from the Hogwarts Express in the *Half-Blood Prince*.

Comment: The point Petra is making is; Harry seems to have all sorts of magic protections, so instead of using magic why not use a large pointy piece of metal

Comment: @user20310 If that's the point Petra is making, I agree that this is a duplicate, as suggested in the comments to the question.

Comment: @tobiasvl That was my point; sorry, never new this question had already been asked. I'm very much new here. How do we know if our our question has already been answered? Thanks.

Comment: @Petra Search before you ask :) but of course, sometimes you fail to find previous questions because you use other terms. In that case, the community finds it for you, like here.